# Loop through all contacts in HubSpot's API

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have set up the connection in Qliksense and got it worked. Now HubSpot returns paginated contacts of maximum 100 for which I need to get pagination done for all the contacts to get.
[image]

This setting doesn't work as there is no total records path i see in the json response to paste in here. Is there any way i can get this done for QlikSense.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I am facing the same issue with Hubspot. Can you please post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REST Connector for Qlikview/Qliksense there is pagination parameter. You can fins more info here:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/REST_connector_help/Content/Connectors_REST/Create-REST-connection/Pagination-scenarios.htm

Although there are so much custom REST implementation that sometimes is easier is just make manually a lot of GET calls by changing parameters with every loop and exit loop when there is no data.

Comment: thanks , i have been through this document , but now the problem is that i cannot find the total records path for hubspot api pagination . Any idea ?

Comment: I would just use for loop and if there is empty table returned break loop